# Locating favicon location

Tags: html, css

[The site](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html) uses a favicon stored in the root, but the https [admin](https://www.inside-guides.co.uk/admin/Default.asp?) section is using the old favicon and I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Does anyone know of a way to find favicon site resources, i.e. where they're coming from? The unsecured pages all use the same head CSS with references to the same favicon, but the admin references no favicon, so I'm baffled as to why it's using the old one on those pages.

Comment: Is `$("[rel^='shortcut'][rel$='icon']")` producing the right link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your site using the selector `document.querySelector("[rel='shortcut icon']")` gets the element:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

You can reveal the element in the html panel with most javascript consoles if you want to see where its being declared in your html. In your case its declared:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's saying 'null' on the admin page though which is where I need to find the location.

Comment: If it produces null then the favicon isnt being set. You can copy the html in my answer and youll get the same favicon on the admin pages

Comment: Would like to know where it's coming from where none is referenced, but the best answer as it solves the issue and is concise. May be a cache issue even though it was cleared.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no favicon.ico in the root of the site, then view the source of the site and look for `<link rel="shortcut icon"/>`. It should have a href attribute. This would tell you the file location.

Comment: Sorry, yes I should've been more accurate - the page source looks normal on unsecured pages, but the secured pages are using the old favicon and I'm not sure where it's coming from. There isn't actually one specified now as I removed the new one, but it's still showing the old one with no favicon referenced.

Comment: @user3025377 then clear your cache. Browsers (at least Chrome) *really* like caching them.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will look for a favicon at */favicon.ico* if they don't see a  tag.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359390/13683677