# Is putting your favicon.ico file in a non-root path a bad idea?

Tags: html, http, cross-browser, browser

When and how do browsers request the favicon.ico file? Do they always check for it in root, or do they read the content of the webpage first to see if the page specifies the location?

I have my favicon.ico path in /images
There is the following tag in each of my pages:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

When I load the page in my browser, it seems to work (I can see the file), but I don't know whether they are making bad requests to my root folder first (where the file doesn't exist), and are later making a request to the link.

I want to minimze 404's and wasted bandwidth, by the browser making incorrect calls to my site.

EDIT: I'm looking for some insight into how browsers work, and request this file, so my site structure is efficient.

Comment: @duskwuff gives great advice. browsers look for favicon in root by default, just to let you know.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Remember that not all requests to your site are for HTML pages! Requests for non-HTML content, like bare image files (e.g, viewing http://example.com/image.jpeg directly in the browser), cannot see a `<link>` tag. Therefore, they must fall back to searching for the shortcut icon in the standard location at `/favicon.ico`.

This still doesn't mean that this needs to be the canonical location, though! You can still keep it in `/images/favicon.ico` if you want - just make sure that a redirect is in place from `/favicon.ico` to wherever your preferred location is.

Comment: So are you saying that a browser will first look in the root location of the site, and then look at the <link> tags, or vice versa or neither ?

Comment: The browser will look at `<link>` tags first. But if the user is looking at something that isn't an HTML page at all, like an image file or a PDF, there's no `<link>` tag to consult, so it falls back to the fixed path.

Comment: Great answer... This helped me too: https://perishablepress.com/block-favicon-url-404-requests/

Comment: Bottom line. save wherever you want, just make sure that the request to /favicon.ico from the root works. Great answer!

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno,duskwuff Do you have a use case in mind where a user might directly request for this resource ? Apparently there is a vulnerability if the websites put this icon on their root path. Any attacker can find if a user is logged-in or not to this website, details here: https://robinlinus.github.io/socialmedia-leak/

Comment: @aka_007 Read my answer: browsers will request favicon.ico when displaying non-HTML content. The presence of the favicon is not itself a vulnerability; any image file on the site can be used to trigger that type of login redirection.

Comment: @duskwuff agreed. I guess this is one of the reasons why website host their resources on CDN. They should also host favicon.ico in a CDN. I wanted to know if there is any security vulnerability in doing so.

Comment: I have a copy of my favicon.ico in my root directory, and a path images/favicon-24-24.png or something like that in my links for various platforms. This seems to cover all cases. Check your favicon here (great tool, not by me : ) http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker