# URL rewriting in ASP.NET Core 2.1 without regex

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.1

My favicon is at `/images/favicon.ico` rather than the root. In `Startup.cs` I can added a redirect to avoid a 404:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
  .AddRedirect("favicon.ico", "images/favicon.ico"));
```

That works nicely, but of course relies on a redirect. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting#regex-examples) also show how to use rewriting, so the user doesn't see a redirect.

I tried this, but get a 404:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
  .AddRewrite("favicon.ico", "images/favicon.ico", skipRemainingRules:true));
```

So I thought that maybe I need to use a dummy regex:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
  .AddRewrite("^(favicon.ico)$", "images/favicon.ico", skipRemainingRules:true));
```

But I still get a 404. How do I make this work?

Comment: Your favicon is in `/images/favicon.ico`, not in `/wwwroot/images/favicon.ico` ?

Comment: Why is the redirect displeasing you ?

Comment: @Wndrr It's in `/wwwroot/images/favicon.ico`. The redirect is unnecessary, probably bad for SEO, and it should be simple to use a rewrite, but my syntax is incorrect and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Ionix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983704/6838730), the rewrite rules must be applied before the call to `UseStaticFiles()`

---

**Old answer, no longer relevant**

Following your question I've done a lot of testing with the `AddRewrite` method and I've tried a lot of things inspired by the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#url-redirect) but nothing worked. At best I got a redirect ...

So my answer is: you can't ! Only a redirect works. If you find a way to make a true rewrite work, please let me know but for now I'll consider this is impossible.

Why not simply use the working solution, the redirect ? Do you *need* a rewrite ?

Comment: Yes I came to the same conclusion! I added a [bug report](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8254) to their repo. Thanks for confirming! (If we get some upvotes maybe someone will take a look at it!)

Comment: Using url rewrites for SEO reasons here and also can't get it to work. You can even just comment out the App.run line in the official documentation and it will not work.

Comment: @SteveGSD And Wndrr see my new answer.